# The last elements are not visible in LazyColumn. Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I take an example from [this codelab](https://developer.android.google.cn/codelabs/jetpack-compose-layouts#5)

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
    setContent {
        //Column(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.LightGray)) {
            //Text(text = "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()

            LazyColumn(state = scrollState, modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Cyan).fillMaxWidth()) {
                items(100) {
                    Text("Item #$it")
                }
            }
        //}

    }
  } 
}
```

But latest element not visible on my scree. P.S I scrolled to the end

[image]

When add  height in column - the last elements are visible, but `LazyColumn` stretches over the entire height

```
LazyColumn(state = scrollState, modifier = 
 Modifier.background(Color.Cyan).fillMaxWidth().height(350.dp)) {         
   items(100) {
    Text("Item #$it")
   }
}
```

[image]

This happens because the column is a root element. Ok, Adding `Column()` in root element and `LazyColumn()` into in root, but I want the `LazyСolumn` to take up the entire height

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
    setContent {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.LightGray)) {
            val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()

            LazyColumn(state = scrollState, modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Cyan).fillMaxWidth()/*.height(350.dp)*/) {
                items(100) {
                    Text("Item #$it")
                }
            }
        }

     }
  }
}
```

The last elements are not visible

Ideally I want to make a scrolling table with a static header

UPD:
When I add Text() On and Under LazyColumn(), also the last elements are not visible

```
setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                Column(modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.LightGray)
                    .fillMaxSize()) {
                    Text(text = "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red).weight(1f)
                    )
                    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()

                    LazyColumn(
                        state = scrollState,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .background(Color.Cyan)
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .weight(4f)
                    ) {
                        items(100) {
                            Text("Item #$it")
                        }
                    }
                    Text(text = "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red).weight(1f))
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Faced with the same problem when you use CoordinatorLayout + Behaviour.

Answer (score 16):

Wrap your `LazyColumn` with `Scaffold` and set `contentPadding` for the `LazyColumn` with the padding values provided by the `Scaffold`:

```
Scaffold { paddingValues ->
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentPadding = paddingValues
    ) {
      ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: i have same problem .. but its not working with this solution

Comment: Solution works! @Vladislav could you please help with the reason behind this fix as well. Thanks!

Comment: Only need to add the Scaffold to wrap the root screen. Applying paddingValues is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
inflater: LayoutInflater,
container: ViewGroup?,
savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
    setContent {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.LightGray)) {
            val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()

            LazyColumn(state = scrollState, modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Cyan).fillMaxSize()) {
                items(100) {
                    Text("Item #$it")
                }
            }
        }

     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Replacing:
`val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()`
with:
`val scrollState = rememberLazyListState(99 /*or use (list.size - 1) if you have a list in you LazyColumn */)`
worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following [`systemBarsPadding`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).systemBarsPadding()) to the modifier of LazyColumn.

I guess it has to do with making the fullscreen activity.

```kotlin
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.systemBarsPadding().fillMaxSize(),
) {
  ...
}
```

Also, It works adding Scaffold which Vladislav said.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like the bottom of your view is under the navigation bar. Check out if you have this line in your activity:

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

You can remove this line if you don't need to place your views under navigation bar.

If you need it, like to make it transparent and place some background view underneath, you can use [Accompanist Insets](https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/). With this library you can add padding respectful to navigation/status bar, like with `Modifier.navigationBarsPadding()`:

```
LazyColumn(
    state = scrollState,
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Cyan)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .navigationBarsPadding()
) {
    items(100) {
        Text("Item #$it")
    }
}
```

Comment: when I add Text() On and Under LazyColum, also the last elements are not visible

Comment: @MarkGlushko `Modifier.navigationBarsPadding` should be added to the top most container, or to the last element in your column